# user interaction: different ways of visualizing data

Tags: interaction-design, interface, info-visualisation, mouse

I have a project which contains a piechart. Every group in the piechart has its key, value, percentage and a description.

Of the ways shown below, which is the best to visualize the data? Is there a better way than these?

*Note*: Groups in legend are shorten for this question, obviously there are more than two.

**Way 1**

[image: way1]

On mouseover of legend or piechart

- loads numbers in piechart
- loads detail text
- selected group will be indented in legend

**Way 2**

[image: way2]

On mouseover of legend or piechart

- loads numbers in piechart
- load title into SELECTED GROUP TITLE
- load detail text into DETAIL TEXT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- I would show the "Selected Group Title" and "Detailtext" as a tooltip/popover in the chart
- and change the background color of the selected group element (much more visible than indenting)

This way you have all your information in one place (the chart) and don't need to look at different places fot the title, description, percentages, ...

Beside that, you shouldn't use pie charts at all, bar charts are a better choice most of the time:

[Pie Charts Are The Worst - Business Insider](http://www.businessinsider.com/pie-charts-are-the-worst-2013-6?IR=T)